# Issues with ezcap284 capture card on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb

I received a capture card today that advertised that it would work with Linux, it is the ezcap284. However, it does not show up in OBS.

This is the lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0ea0:2209 Ours Technology, Inc.
```

I have verified that the device is fully functional, it records just fine, I just cannot get it to record when it is connected to the computer.

The capture card comes with Windows and Mac drivers, but i'd really prefer not to set up a VM just to use this capture card.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @brauliobo unfortunately not. No one is interested in making an ezcap driver apparently